# Cordova Unzip File should replace earlier Unzipped file

Tags: ios, cordova, sencha-touch

I am unzipping "content.zip" and it gets unzipped as "content".
Second time when I unzip an updated "content.zip", I dont find "content" updated with the new data. 
Instead "content" still has the old data. 
Where is the new "content.zip" unzipped? 
Or during Unzip can we replace the old unzipped Content?

I am using Cordova Plugin https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/zip.git

The Code is

```
zip.unzip(zippedContentUrl,'cdvfile://localhost/persistent/',function(){
                                           console.log("completed unzip");
                                           });
```

If the second time i am going to unzip "zippedContentUrl", I dont see any updated content under cdvfile://localhost/persistent/zippedContentUrl/

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the file prior to unzipping it again? Perhaps the plugin doesn't like overwriting files. I'm not familiar enough with the plugin to know, but it's a thought.

Comment: Hey Kerri! I got this covered.
The problem had been in the Zip file which had an unidentified .saz file which the plugin dint know how to unzip it. 
The plugin I used for unzipping is quite cool and replaces the older files and overwrites.